# Google maps sceen remains white with a google logo on the bottom

Tags: android, google-maps

I have created a google map activity and created a corresponding api key following the instructions given in the *google_maps_api.xml* file.
But when I run the code on the device through usb, it shows a blank fragment with the google logo on the bottom. 
I have checked the log and it says:

> Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
>   Ensure that the following Android Key exists:

In the google console it says the api is registered with the application and is enabled.

What would be the cause of the this error ?

Comment: Have  you updated `<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">` with key info, in your `google_maps_api.xml` ?

Comment: yes, I have updated both google_maps_api.xml with the api key

Comment: do you have internet connection?

Comment: I have solved the issue. It turn out as I have followed the link for generating the key,  and my MapsActivity was created within a different package, the application package name used for the key was not correct. It used **cd.acgt.acgtexp.activities** as the **activities** is the package for the activity instead of simply **cd.acgt.actexp**

Comment: Oh. Great! Remember to have internet connection enabled for the maps to work.